# Suggestions For String and DateTime utility functions' Library using Extension Methods

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I'm writing a library of Extension Methods for String and DateTime utility functions in C#. Can you please help me out by suggesting the useful utlity functions for String and DateTime you may want to be part of it ? With your suggestions I can make it more cohesive and Collective.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I've seen quite few of these. Have you not found any not really suiting your needs?

Comment: What functions have you already come up with? Providing a list would help others by giving them more ideas. Or you might keep getting answers that list what you already have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value){
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
public static string Reverse(this string value) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        char[] chars = value.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(chars);
        value = new string(chars);
    }
    return value;
}
public static string ToTitleCase(this string value) {
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
}
public static string ToTitleCaseInvariant(this string value) {
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
}
```

Trivial, but slighty nicer to call.

Comment: The second one ought to be bool IsEmpty(this string value) {...} as a null object couldn't have an instance call.

Comment: @Stevo3000 - yes it can!! Extension methods can be called on null. Seriously. Try it.

Comment: you can have a string initialized to null and still have it call the Extension Methods.

Comment: @Marc - Fair enough, just doesn't seem logical.

Comment: @Stevo3000 - Why not. Here's the code Example: 
bool isItThere = Request.QueryString["name"].IsNullOrEmpty();

Comment: @Marc - Your function is completely logical, what I was suggesting wasn't logical is that it looks like you are caling an instance method on a possibly null value.

Comment: Purely as a convenience - s.Foo() vs string.Foo(s)

Comment: I didn't undestand the purpose of the first one, till you guys talked about the extensions call on null value, thanks, nice trick

Comment: Definatly conveiant, and if we were targeting 3.5 it'd be the first extension I wrote. So are extension methods always valid on null objects? If so that seem confusing.

Comment: @Stevo3000 - always. It is just a compiler trick, that translates obj.SomeMethod() to SomeClass.SomeMethod(obj), and null is perfectly legal as an *argument*. There is no null-check.

Comment: @Marc - Cheers for clearing that up. I guess it gives conveniance and power as a trade off for slightly confusing code.

Comment: No need to reverse one-character strings...
if( self != null && self.Length > 1 )

Answer (score 5):

What about methods that don't specifically *extend* string or DateTime, but rather *target* or return a string or DateTime?  Then you could build some `int` and `TimeSpan` methods as well, so you can write fluent interfaces like:

```
  DateTime yesterday =  1.Days().Ago();
```

.

```
public static TimeSpan Days(this int value)
{
    return new TimeSpan(value, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static TimeSpan Hours(this int value)
{
    return new TimeSpan(value, 0, 0);
}

public static TimeSpan Minutes(this int value)
{
    return new TimeSpan(0, value, 0);
}

//...
```

.

```
public static DateTime Ago(this TimeSpan value)
{
    return DateTime.Now.Add(value.Negate());
}

public static DateTime FromNow(this TimeSpan value)
{
   return DateTime.Now.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**String Extensions**

1. `MakeTitle` -- Make a title from a TitleCase string, .i.e, turn "FooBar" in to "Foo Bar".  I find this very useful for printing Enums:  `fooEnum.ToString("g").MakeTitle()`
2. `Collapse` -- Trim whitespace from both ends and collapse all internal spaces to a single space.
3. `IsNothing` -- Like IsNullOrEmpty, but trims whitespace first, helpful for TextBox inputs that you don't want to be just spaces, but set to null if nothing was input.

**DateTime Extensions**

1. `EndOfDay` -- set time to 11:59:59 PM on the given date
2. `StartOfDay` -- set time to 12:00:00 AM on the given date

Comment: IsNullOrEqual - do you mean IsNullOrEmpty?

Comment: Duh -- I got to stop answering before I have my coffee.

Comment: StartOfDay is just DateTime.Date

Comment: I like the symmetry with EndOfDay -- though, it could also be used to give business hours instead of midnight -- same with EndOfDay.

Answer (score 1):

**String Extensions**

```
static string ToCamelCase(this string s) {...}  // Converts a string into Camel Notation, useful for code generation
static string ToPascalCase(this string s) {...} // Converts a string into Pascal Notation
static int [Soundex][1](this string s) {...}      // Gets the soundex of a string
```

**DateTime Extensions**

```
static bool IsWithinRange(this DateTime d, DateTime start, DateTime end) {...}
static string [ToRelativeTime][2](this DateTime d) {...}
```